# Script not inserting inner html on footer element

Tags: javascript, html, footer, innerhtml

**HTML Code:**

```
<footer id="footer">
    </footer>
    <script src="/scripts/Animation.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/MenuControls.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/FooterControls.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/BannerControls.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**FooterControls script:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var xmlhttp;
    var e = document.getElementById("footer");
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "SharedFooter.html", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    e.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
};
```

**InnerHTML to insert: SharedFooter.html**

```
<p>
        Author: XXXXX<br>
        <a href="student@Hotmail.com">student@example.com</a>
    </p>
```

Basically inserting the ShareFooter.html text into the html page where the id = footer which is used for the footer element. Its not working all other scripts similarly work. Could the html tag not be loading in time? TIA

Comment: you should clarify the document type ```xmlhttp.responseType = "document";``` before send() method.

Comment: tried that hasn't done anything

Comment: check can you get response text in console.

Comment: found something : xmlhttp.open("GET", "SharedFooter.html", false);
  this line in the script is being underline in the console with this message  Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: Add a leading slash to the value of the `src` attribute of the `script` tag for FooterControl.js?

Comment: Also, you don't need `window.onload` because the script tags are properly placed at the end of the body, so they don't execute until all the other HTML has been loaded

Comment: Remind me to never copy paste code, cheers user2182349!!